# Connect host nginx and msql with a docker container of php5-fpm

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, containers

I have a legacy Wordpress installation that run with Nginx/MySQL and php5-fpm and I have to move it to a recent VPS that features php7-fpm.

I'd like to leverage the new host VPS already installed Nginx/MySQL and install and use a container for managing php5 requests.

I pulled the official [php5-fpm](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) image from Docker Hub

```
docker pull php:5.6-fpm-alpine
```

... then I run the the image remapping the port 9000 where php5-fpm is listening and mounting the wordpress root folder (uncertain about that) and mysql socket, without -d flag in order to see the logs live:

```
docker run --name phpFpm5.6 -p 127.0.0.1:9999:9000 -v /home/ubuntu/www/html:/var/www/html -v /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/tmp/mysql.sock php:5.6-fpm-alpine
```

Here's the console logs:

```
[21-Aug-2017 12:36:19] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[21-Aug-2017 12:36:19] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
172.17.0.1 -  21/Aug/2017:12:37:09 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
172.17.0.1 -  21/Aug/2017:12:39:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
```

When I request the index page from a browser, I'm getting a 404 (not found) response.

Nginx directive:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Any clue is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Think of container as the remote server. Now the mapping of ports that you are doing `9999:9000` tells docker to connect port number `9999` on host to port number `9000` of the container.

Now in your nginx directive, the one running inside container, you are redirecting at `9999`. Instead, it should be `9000`.

According to your scenario, all resources are served by the container at port `9999`, but port `9999` of container is not accessible to host.

Comment: i think the fastcgi_pass being mapped to localhost can cause the failure too

Comment: @omu_negru Yeah, either the mapping can be changed or the redirection port may be changed to `9000`